# php can someone tell me what i am doing wrong please

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin

the problem i got is that when i get information back from the database, i only get two raws not 4 . can someone help me out as i cant find any problems

this is the code

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT INCIDENT_ID FROM appreports WHERE POSTCODE = 'CF14' ");


while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $output[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
```

**this is the screenshot of the appreports table in database** [image]

Comment: I'm not quite clear what is broken – what exactly is the problem, and what code do you think is responsible for it?

Comment: Please be more specific with what is wrong. We don't know what your output is supposed to be so we can't tell what doesn't work

Comment: You might want to read up on sql injection.

Comment: well as you can see from the db screenshot , its uploading the info correctly but when i search the database using postcode . it fails to find 4 raws that match .

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Ben, please don't deface your questions and re-ask them. Instead, take a little time to edit your question and clarify what you are asking. If you do a good enough job of that, we'll be able to re-open your question and it will help you to get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're joining *two* database tables using an 'INNER' join. If there's no corresponding `POSTCODE` in the joined table, this row will not be returned.

To return all `appregistrations` with the specified mobile number, **optionally** with an `appreport`, use this;

```
SELECT * FROM appregistration
LEFT JOIN
    `appreports`
     ON `appreports`.`POSTCODE` = `appregistration`.`POSTCODE`

WHERE `appregistration`.`MOBILE_NUMBER` = '$mobile'
```

Comment: so what will be the solution, can you help plz

Comment: Basically, your query does what it's supposed to do, find `appreports` with a *matching* `appregistration` that has the specified phone-number? If there's no matching appregistration (based on postcode) it should not be returned, you cannot connect just a 'random' record

Comment: it looks at appregistration table given mobile number and finds the postcodes match in appreports table . but the problem is that its not showing 4 raws of information, its only showing 2

Comment: Because there are appreports records without a matching POSTCODE in the appregistraion table... Try this `SELECT * FROM appreports WHERE POSTCODE NOT IN(SELECT POSTCODE FROM appregistration);` this will show you which rows do not have a matching record

Comment: shows that raw 2 and 4 dont match the postcode , which they clearly do as seen on the screenshot

Comment: The screenshot only shows the `appreports` table? From that screenshot alone, it's not possible to check if a matching `appregistration` exists?

Comment: the screenshot shows appreports table , would you like me to take screenshot of appregistration table

Comment: I've given you a query in my previous comment that says that there are records that are NOT matched by POSTCODE. There may be spaces in one of the tables, or simply missing postcodes. I don't need a screenshot, as that query already should give you the answer as to why some rows are not returned. Please make yourself familiar with JOINS in SQL; http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

You are inner joining on POSTCODE and from that set you are filtering on a given MOBILE_NUMBER.  You have 4 of the same POSTCODES here, so i'm guessing the issue is the MOBILE_NUMBER. Remove the WHERE clause and you may be back to 4 rows.

Comment: But doesn't that remove the purpose of the script? Filter rows by phone-number?

Comment: i am using number to find the postcode of someone , then i am using the postcode and listing matched postcodes . which should show 4 raws which match the same postcode

Comment: Are you 100% sure the postcodes match? I've given you a query that says otherwise. The POSTCODE field in one of the tables may contain leading/trailing spaces that are invisible inside PhpMyAdmin, but are there anyway.

Comment: @ben you are missing the mobile_number column from your screenshot Can you add it?

Answer (score -1):

If you want return ALL rows with mobile number is $mobile at appreports table use this:

```
SELECT `INCIDENT_ID`, `INVESTIGATION`, `TYPE_OF_INCIDENT`, `DESCRIPTION`
FROM `appreports`                    
WHERE `appregistration`.`MOBILE_NUMBER` = '$mobile'"
```

If you want return ALL rows with mobile number is $mobile at appreports table and the information at appregistration table if this exist use this:

```
   SELECT `INCIDENT_ID`, `INVESTIGATION`, `TYPE_OF_INCIDENT`, `DESCRIPTION`
   FROM `appreports`
   FULL OUTER JOIN `appregistration` 
   ON `appreports`.`POSTCODE` = `appregistration`.`POSTCODE`
   WHERE `appregistration`.`MOBILE_NUMBER` = '$mobile'")
```

Comment: i used the second cluse , still only showing two raws not 4

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the error in second query. this must work now. you can read this http://en.kioskea.net/faq/26824-mysql-how-to-choose-inner-or-outer-joins

Comment: thank you but its showing error , Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ..... on line 19 null

Comment: You cannot perform a find like that on an outer join and it doesn't make sense; basically your second query says; get all rows with the specified phone-number and rows for which we couldn't find a phone number... The error is probably caused by the fact that some rows don't have a matching appregistration, in which case all those fields are `NULL`, so you cannot compare `[no appregistration found].MOBILE_NUMBER = "$mobile"`

Comment: check sql syntax and add FULL before OUTER.

Comment: i just tried thsi code "$sql = mysql_query("SELECT INCIDENT_ID FROM appreports WHERE POSTCODE = 'CF14' ");
" which shows only two raws, but it should show 4 raws

Comment: Try this `SELECT INCIDENT_ID FROM appreports WHERE POSTCODE LIKE '%CF14%';`. If that gives you 4 rows, the POSTCODE field contains spaces, try to remove them with this; `UPDATE appreports SET POSTCODE = TRIM(POSTCODE);`

Comment: thanks but this did not work sorry